# Python/xlwings set excel table style to "none"

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

I have exported a dataframe to Excel using xlwings and am trying to format it as a table.  I want to apply the "None" style but can't figure out how to specify the "None."

This line works:

```
table = sheet.tables.add(source=sheet["A1"].expand(), name = 'TableName', table_style_name = "TableStyleLight1")
```

But instead of "TableStyleLight1" I want "None". I have tried "", '', 0, "None" and none of them work.

Comment: Have you tried just `None`, not `"None"`?

Comment: From the [docs](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/api.html#xlwings.main.Tables.add): table_style_name (str, default 'TableStyleMedium2') – Possible strings: 'TableStyleLightN'' (where N is 1-21), 'TableStyleMediumN' (where N is 1-28), 'TableStyleDarkN' (where N is 1-11)

Comment: @user17242583 Yes, that didn't work either

Comment: @ BigBen There doesn't seem to be an option for 0, as 1 applies some kind of format in each case.

Comment: What I'm saying is, based on the docs this doesn't seem to be possible using `tables.add`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.api` to access the native object, and clear the formatting after creating the table:

```
table = sheet.tables.add(source=ws.range('I20:N40'), name='UnformattedTable')
sheet.api.ListObjects('UnformattedTable').TableStyle = ""  # Windows specific
```

But as mentioned in the comments, it doesn't seem to be supported using `tables.add` directly.
xlwings has a [missing feature](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/missing_features.html) page with an example on using `.api`. Note the above example is for windows, the api for mac is slightly different.

Comment: Thanks @c_48.  I was hoping to do this without an extra step but looks like it can't be avoided.